# I would like to convert data type from within a nested list

Tags: python, return, return-value, nested-lists

Using Jupyter Notebooks/python 3.x; I have been trying to figure out how to convert a string to floats in a list. I am not sure how to best accomplish this and any advice would be much appreciated. I got so far as to converting the individual items but am getting various errors when I try to save the data back into the test list.

```
my_test_list=[]
my_test_list= [[ '7','8','9','10','11'],['12','13','14','15','16']]

for i in my_test_list:
    for x in i:
        try:
            x=float(x)
            print(x)
        except ValueError:
            pass

print(my_test_list)
```

Yields the result:

```
7.0
8.0
9.0
10.0
11.0
12.0
13.0
14.0
15.0
16.0
[['7', '8', '9', '10', '11'], ['12', '13', '14', '15', '16']]
```

I would like `print(my_test_list)` to yield the result:

```
[[7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0], [12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0]]
```

Comment: are all the innerlists the same length?

Comment: How deeply nested could the lists be?

Comment: the innerlists will not be the same length; the lists will not be nested any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this one line

```
test = [['7', '8', '9', '10', '11'], ['12', '13', '14', '15', '16']]


test = [[float(x) for x in l] for l in test]
```

Comment: I'm using the try/except because its possible to have actual words instead of just numbers too. I forgot that part I was so focused on how to get my floats back out of my for loops.

Answer (score 1):

this is really fast and easy with numpy

```
import numpy
print(numpy.array([[ '7','8','9','10','11'],['12','13','14','15','16']],dtype=float))
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nuno Palma's answer, but there is no explanation of why this code works while yours does not.  Simply, your code:

```
for i in my_test_list:
for x in i:
    try:
        x=float(x)
        print(x)
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

never actually saves the converted x to my_test_list.  While the provided answer is much more concise, your code could work with a simple addition:

```
output_list = []
for i in my_test_list:
for x in i:
    try:
        x=float(x)
        print(x)
        output_list[i].append(x)
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

The accepted answer is essentially a shorthand for this.

Comment: thanks! I ended up having to use .index() as well to get this to work based off a suggestion a friend told me over the phone.